# How to multiply vector with a matrix from a different class and header file?

Tags: c++11

I want to multiply a vector with a matrix (from a different class and header file) in a Vector Class by overloading the * operator.

The vector class won't recognize the Matrix and I even used the Friend keyword.

this is the constructor code:

I get an error in the cell part and += part.

## Constructor

```
Matrix operator*(Matrix matrix, Vector vector)
{
    double sum_of_elements = 0;
    Matrix res(matrix.getnumrows, matrix.getnumcols);
    for (int i = 0; i <matrix.getnumcols(); i++)
    {
            for (int m = 0; m < vector.Index; m++) {
                res.cell[i] += matrix.cell[i][m] * vector.cell[i];
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

This is the header for the constructor:
Notice that I've used the friend keyword.

## Header

```
class Vector
{
    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, const Vector &vec);
    friend Matrix operator*(Matrix matrix, Vector vector);
    private:
        int Index;
        std::vector<float> cell;
    public:
        Vector();
        Vector(float a, float b, float c);

    ~Vector();

};
```

This is the source file where the code should perform its task

## Source

```
try {

        Matrix m1(3, 3, 1.0);
        Matrix m2(3, 4, 1.0);

        m1(1, 2) = 14.92;
        m1(0, 0) = 4.2;
        Vector v1{9.1,1.2,8.2};
        Vector v2 = m1 * v1;
        std::cout << "v2:" << v2 << std::endl;;
    }
    catch (std::exception &e) {
        std::cout << "Exception: " << e.what() << "!" << std::endl;
    }
    catch (...) {
        std::cout << "Unknown exception caught!" << std::endl;
    }
```

The output should look like this:

```
v2:[47.62
132.644
18.5]
```

But I get 6 error messages:

```
Error   C2248   'Matrix::cell': cannot access private member declared in class 'Matrix' vector.cpp  25  

Error   C2440   'initializing': cannot convert from 'Matrix' to 'Vector'    source.cpp  17  

Error   C2676   binary '+=': '_Ty' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator   vector.cpp       25  

Error   C3867   'Matrix::getnumrows': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member    vector.cpp  21
    
Error   C3867   'Matrix::getnumcols': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member    vector.cpp  21
    
Error (active)  E0312   no suitable user-defined conversion from "Matrix" to "Vector" exists         Source.cpp     17
```

Comment: Please, edit your question following this [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  There is a lot of wrong things in here and not a lot of information. If your code isn't too long, consider uploading it all, it will be much easier.

Comment: You made `operator*` a friend of `Vector`, but apparently not of `Matrix`, so it cannot access the private member `Matrix::cell`

Comment: `Vector v2 = m1 * v1;` doesn't make sense - `m1 * v1` produces a `Matrix`, not a `Vector`.

Comment: `getnumrows` is apparently a member function, but you use it as if it were a member variable. If you want to call it, add a pair of parentheses. Same with `getnumcols`

Comment: `res.cell[i] += ...` Here, `res.cell[i]` presumably represents the whole row in the matrix, not a single element. What does it mean to add to it?

Comment: No it produces a vectir not a matrix

Comment: I can't debug it, and I tried numerous times to solve it bit it won't work and there are methods completely new to me.

Comment: The real problem here is that the cell variable exists in the Matrix header file as a private member. I want to acces it in Vector header file and cpp file.